# STM32F072 LSI Calibration

Tags: stm32, cpu-registers

I recently started with embedded programming and currently I'm tasked with LSI Calibration based on LSE clock, this would be useful when the device enters low power mode. Based on this reference manual:

https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/c2/f8/8a/f2/18/e6/43/96/DM00031936.pdf/files/DM00031936.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031936.pdf

I don't see any registers for LSI calibration like the ones HSICAL, HSI14CAL...

Does this mean the calibration for LSI is not achievable before using it as RTC Clock ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're driving the RTC fom the LSI, you can adjust the sync_prediv and async_prediv values to make the RTC tick at the correct rate. You can work these out from measuring the actual rate of the LSI against the LSE (or HSI, or HSE). This document (especially section 4) might be helpful:
[Calibrating STM32F0x1, STM32F0x2 and STM32F0x8 lines internal RC oscillators](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/8c/71/55/1e/ae/fd/41/cd/DM00050140.pdf/files/DM00050140.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00050140.pdf)

If you have an LSE, why not just use that for the RTC and disable the LSI? Power consumption in low power modes will be similar with either source, and if you can use the LSE with "low-drive" power, consumption with the LSE will actually be slightly lower than LSI.

Comment: So what I would have to do is compute HSI frequency based on LSE then calibrate it. then use the HSI frequency to get the calibration for the LSI? My boss is set on using LSI when the device runs on the battery and I'm not that experienced to change his mind. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That would be the correct sequence, since the LSE is likely to be the most accurate clock source you have, so everything needs to start with that. It would also be worth pointing out the the LSI has no guarantees about its temperature or voltage stability, so its frequency can/will change with temperature and supply voltage. I really would recommend using it only if you need very rough timekeeping.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the LSI isn't trimmable in this part, and as stated in the datasheet the typical frequency is 40 kHz, but can be anywhere between 30 and 50 kHz, it isn't a great choice for an RTC if you require any kind of accuracy.

I suppose if you can measure the difference between the LSI and LSE clocks, you could compensate for the time offset in the RTC when you know whether you're running fast or slow, but that will be very temperature dependant.